# random generator function javascript

Tags: javascript, function, random

I'm making a guessing game for class. I pretty much have it done, but the biggest problem I've had was making the string randomize itself after the game ends. It picks a random letter if the page refreshes but the objective is to keep track of stats so refreshing is out.

Here's my javascript code:

```
var lettersChar = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", 
"l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

function randomFunc() {
    var randomMath = lettersChar[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
    lettersChar.length)];
    return randomMath;
}

//variables
var randomChar = randomFunc();

//array where user input will be stored
var userChoices = [];

var wins = 0;

var losses = 0;

var guesses = 9;

//keypress event
document.onkeyup = function (event) {

var userGuess = event.key;

    var userOptions = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
"k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", 
"z"];

//if guess is correct, +1 to win and refresh game and generate new letter
if (userOptions.indexOf(userGuess) > -1) {

    if (userGuess === randomChar) {
        wins++;
        guesses = 9;
        randomFunc();
        console.log(wins);
    }
    //if guess is incorrect, then print wrong guess and -1 to guesses left
    else if (userGuess !== randomChar) {
        guesses--;
        userChoices.push(userGuess);
    }
    //If guess reaches to 0 add +1 to loss and restarts game
    if (guesses === 0) {
        losses++;
        guesses = 9;
        userChoices = [];
        randomChar;
    }
}
```

I've tried invoking the function and it doesn't appear to work for me at this moment. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please create a working snippet and tell us exactly where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the last line you posted:

`randomChar;`

You're just declaring randomChar again and not doing anything with it. If you want to randomize it after the game ends, you should call `randomFunc` again:

```
randomChar = randomFunc();
```

Same for when the user wins: replace with

```
if (userGuess === randomChar) {
    wins++;
    guesses = 9;
    randomChar = randomFunc();
    console.log(wins);
}
```

Comment: Only at the very beginning - not on win or on lose. (ofc don't want to declare a new variable scoped incorrectly, just want to *assign* to the global variable)

Comment: Thank you so much. Why does only using randomFunc() not work? I thought using that would invoke the function. I have much to learn!

Comment: randomFunc generates a random character and returns that character, but doesn't do anything else with it - you have to assign the result of the function to the variable you want to change.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you again